# Is it necessary to write about the set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have this set, represented by extension:

$\{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, ...\}$

Now I must represent it by comprehension:

$$\{x \in \mathbb{N} : 2^{x-1} \text{ is power of } 2\}$$

Is it necessary to write "is power of 2" ?

Comment: it is $$\{2^n|0\leq n\leq 7\} $$

Comment: $2^{x-1}$ is always a power of two (except perhaps for $x=0$ if negative powers don’t count). So $\{x\in \mathbb N: \mbox{$2^{x-1}$ is a power of two} \}$ is the set of all positive integers.

Comment: My question is if i can write {$x \in \mathbb{N}$ : $2^{x-1}$} without "is pow of 2"

Comment: What you have written there does not make any sense. Currently, your set is all $x$ in the natural numbers. The righthand side condition does not "restrict" your set the way you need it to.

Comment: Edited, is good now ? ${\mathbb{N}}$ start from 1,2, 3.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ typically includes 0

Comment: My teacher, said that the natural numbers were created to count, therefore, it does not include it

Comment: Some people don’t include it but you should be aware that 0 is a natural number in most of mathematics.  If someone asked you to count how many sheep are in an empty field you would say 0.

Comment: @QthePlatypus I disagree.  It depends entirely on context, and (to some extent) the tastes of the mathematician who is working with $\mathbb{N}$.  Personally, I don't like to include $0$, and write either $\mathbb{N}_0$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ for the nonnegative integers.  In any event, I've witnessed near fisticuffs over the "proper" definition of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148354/set-builder-notation-can-i-switch-whats-written-on-the-left-and-right-of-the-v/

Answer (score 3):

The set you must represent has the following form:

$$
\{2^n: \, 0 \le n \le 7\}
$$

Comment: My question is if i can write {$x \in \mathbb{N}$ : $2^{x-1}$} without "is pow of 2"

Comment: You have ignored ...+oo included in the set description.

Comment: The first time I read the question, there isn't $+\infty$. Mattiu, you can write directly $\{2^{x-1}: \, x \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ...\}$$
$$A=\{2^{n-1}|n\in \mathbb {N} \}$$

$$A=\{x| x=2^{n-1},n\in \mathbb {N} \}$$

Comment: What mean x/x ?

Comment: My question is if i can write {$x \in \mathbb{N}$ : $2^{x-1}$} without "is pow of 2"

Comment: No, you can not . That does not make sense.

Comment: Ok, but "is pow of 2" included is good ¿?

Comment: No, because that will be the set of all positive integers. because for every positive integer,$ 2^n$ is a power of 2.

Comment: I edited my answer, see now

Comment: is good now ???

Comment: Not yet, you need to edit again.

Comment: You want x to be a power of 2 not $ 2^x$

Comment: You have ignored ...+oo in the set description.

Answer (score 0):

$\{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128... +\infty\}$
= { $2^n$ : n non-negative integer }
= { n : n = $2^k$ for some non-negative integer k }.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be

$$\{ x \in \mathbb{N} \; | \; \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \; x = 2^{n-1} \},$$

which would be read aloud as "the set of all $x$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that there exists an $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ where $x = 2^{n-1}$."